# Appending records to GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

If I have 'see more' button in the footer of grid view. when I click on it , I need to append more records from DB like 'Face Book'. I need to do that without  make full post back on grid.
Is there way to do that using J Query, Jason, or any thing else

Comment: With grid view you can not do that, try the repeater.

Comment: Can I get an example for using repeater to do that ?

Comment: Do you need server controls in GridView rows? Do you have any server code in `RowDataBound` event handler?

Comment: yes I need server side for **RowDataBound** and **RowCommand**

Comment: Then you can't do this asynchronously. This events accessible only if you do data binding on server

Comment: Consider using UpdatePanel for making a partial postback (Ajax), this way you can rebind the grid if you want.

Answer (score 0):

As @Aristos said, you won't be able to append the rows using a `GridView`, as it's bound on the server side. You could, however, create a web service which returns pages of data. These could be appended to a `<ul>` which you've created with [a repeater](http://www.netrostar.com/Tutorials-91-ASP.NET%20Tutorial.%20How%20to%20use%20Repeater):

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string Format(int offset, int limit) {
    //  return data from your database here
```

Then from jQuery,

```
var currentPage = 0;
var numPerPage = 30;
$.ajax({
    url: '/YourService.asmx/GetData',
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'offset': (numPerPage * ++currentPage), 'limit': numPerPage}),
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
    success: function(response){
        // response.d contains your formatted results. If you have a <ul>, you could append them simply by doing:
        $.each(response.d, function() {
            $('<li/>').html(this).appendTo('#yourList');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What about using gridview,controls.add(gridview Data row) ? is it useful?